# Adding today's date to presentation slide--added but can't update

Tags: google-apps-script, google-slides

In Google Slides I'm able to add today's date to my first slide using this script, however the next time it runs it adds another text box with the date on top of the other date, seeing both dates on top of each other, makes a mess.  I cannot find how to delete the date before writing the new one, or overwrite it.

the code to write the date:

```
function myFunction() {
 var date = new Date();
 var months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", 
 "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]
 var slide = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation().getSlides()[0];
 var shape = slide.insertShape(SlidesApp.ShapeType.TEXT_BOX, 300, 200, 300, 60);
 var textRange = shape.getText();
 textRange.setText(months[date.getMonth()]+' '+date.getDate()+', '+date.getFullYear());
```

Thank you,

Comment: If you want to run the script when the presentation is started, unfortunately, in the current stage, [the triggers for Slides](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/) are "Open", "Install" and "Time-driven (clock)", yet. By this, the script cannot be run when the presentation is started. As a workaround, how about using "Open" and/or "Time-driven (clock)"? If this was not what you want, I apologize.

Comment: I'm new to this and learning quite a bit.  Right now I have a chart in my slides that comes from google sheets, and is updated every 15 minutes using a time driven trigger.  I saw in those triggers I could do one at midnight, and was going to try that to update the date on my intro slide.  But are you saying that won't work to have that run my date script?  I won't worry about the date then, just frustrating that I can do that easily on microsoft powerpoint, and on google sheets.  But not get it to work on slides...

Comment: About ``I have a chart in my slides that comes from google sheets, and is updated every 15 minutes using a time driven trigger.``, you also run the script in your question when this trigger is run. If my understanding is correct, I think that the date is modified. If this didn't work, can you provide the detail information? I would like to correctly understand and confirm it.

Comment: I haven't tried this with a trigger yet.  Just hitting the run button on the script editor right now.  It does put the date on the slide as expected.  But when I hit run again, it's puts another text box with the date on top of the old one.  But you can still see the old one underneath, creating a mashed up mess lol.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I thought that I could understand about the issue of script. So I proposed a modified script. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the result you want, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You want to put a text box including date to the 1st page of Slides.
- You want to overwrite the text box for putting date when the text box is existing.

If my understanding is correct, how about using "title" of the text box? Please think of this as just one of several answers. The modified sample script is as follows. In this modification, the identification name of the text box is used by the title of text box. The flow of this script is as follows.

1. Retrieve all shapes from the 1st page of Slides.
2. Retrieve the text box for putting date by the title of text box.
3. If the text box with the title is existing, the text of text box is overwritten by date which is a text.
4. If the text box with the title is not existing, new text box is inserted by putting the date.

#### Modified script:

```
function myFunction() {
  var title = "sampleTitle"; // Please set this.

  var date = new Date();
  var months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
  var slide = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation().getSlides()[0];
  var date = months[date.getMonth()]+' '+date.getDate()+', '+date.getFullYear();
  var shapes = slide.getShapes();
  var s = shapes.filter(function(e) {return e.getTitle() == title});
  if (s.length > 0) {
    s[0].getText().setText(date);
  } else {
    var shape = slide.insertShape(SlidesApp.ShapeType.TEXT_BOX, 300, 200, 300, 60).setTitle(title);
    var textRange = shape.getText();
    textRange.setText(date);
  }
}
```

#### References:

- [getTitle()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/shape#gettitle)
- [setTitle()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/shape#settitletitle)

Comment: 100% what I was looking for.  I knew someone would be smarter than Google lol, thank a bunch!

Comment: @Mark B I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.